# How can I wrap other model classes in one class neatly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

I made a wrapper, and recently I've reflected about what is a poor design decision in my opinion, however, I'm not sure what would be the better alternative.

Currently, my wrapper works like this (names changed):

```py
    import wrapper
    api = wrapper.Api(params...)
    # fetch fetches data from the API
    objects = wrapper.model.fetch(api, params...)
    # get_special might be only relevant to a certain object type
    other_objects = wrapper.other_model.get_special(api, params...)
```

Obviously, passing the API as a parameter isn't very oop-y, and regardless it just looks bad. I considered just putting all of those classes in the API class, but I don't think that's a good idea, either. What would be a better design choice?

Thanks in advance :D

As per request, I'm adding more details.
My application is a wrapper for the website launchlibrary.net, which provides data about rocket launches. It's available here - https://github.com/Plutoberth/python-launch-library

Basically, I'm not sure how to implement this in a way that is both tidy and doesn't require you to pass the API each time. My ideal way would be like this, but I think that would require adding those functions in the API, which would make it quite huge.

```py
import launchlibrary as ll # the wrapper
api = ll.Api(params..)
launches = api.Launch(params...)
```

I guess that this is more of a design question than an implementation one. Implementing that piece of code would be trivial, but it'd make my API class huge.

Comment: Can you explain more what your code does and what exactly wrapper is for? Also, why do you want to wrap classes in classes exactly?

Comment: @user2379875 Hey there. I added more info to the question.

Comment: And what is the goal of your wrapper? Usually, a wrapper should hide all details of what it's wrapping and provide it's own simplified interface to make working with whatever was wrapped easier. So from the users perspective, they shouldn't see any of the implementation details of the launch library. You can create a class that has attributes initialized with the classes you need from the launch library. And your class can have methods to accomplish whatever you need to do.

Comment: @user2379875 I did. The wrapper isn't supposed to be super heavy, and I think that functionality wise it is alright. I'm looking for a way to somehow access my model classes from within my API object.

Comment: If you don't want to pass the api each time, the api needs to be part of a class so than you can refer to it as self.api within the methods. Do you have the full code of the class? I could give you better advice if I have a more clear picture of what you are doing.

Comment: These are the relevant files - https://github.com/Plutoberth/python-launch-library/blob/master/launchlibrary/api.py , https://github.com/Plutoberth/python-launch-library/blob/master/launchlibrary/models.py . I just want to devise a way in which this separation is kept, and yet you don't have to pass the API to the class every time you call a model.

Comment: You would need your own class that has the api as an attribute, and than calls the models through its own interface and passes self.api. So you can use your interface instead of the modals. So like wrapper.model.my_fetch(params...), which calls the original fetch method and uses self.api. A wrapper should make dealing with the code it's wrapping easier and more clear.

Comment: @user2379875 That much is obvious. I was more looking for a way to do this without redefining all of the functions. I thought about overriding __getattr__ and adding references to my classes there, but I think that might be unclean.

Comment: You could try a partial to freeze an arguments: https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial, I usually go with the cleanest most readable solution even if it's a bit more verbose, as long as it does not majorly impact performance.

Comment: @user2379875 I don't think that I'm gonna use that, but thanks for the suggestion! I think that I'm going to override \_\_getattr\_\_ , and just have it return the model. That way, you could do api_object.Launch.fetch(params...), without passing the API object.